# this.props.items.map is not a function on using react with redux to fetch api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to build my react app using redux but encountering this error, Error:this.props.items.map is not a function on using react with Redux on fetching the API as shown in the code.

```
 render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <div className="container">
            <Header />
            <Route exact path="/" render={props => (
              <React.Fragment>
                <Todos 
                />
              </React.Fragment>
            )} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
```

---

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getItems = () => {
  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=10')
    .then(res => dispatch({
      type: 'GET_ITEMS',
      payload: res.data
    }))
}
```

---

```
const initialState = { items: {} };

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_ITEMS': return {
      ...state,
      items: action.payload
    };   
    default: return state
  }
}
```

---

```
class Todos extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      (this.props.items.map)((todo) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          {todo.title}
        </React.Fragment>
      ))

   )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  items: state.items
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Todos);
```

> I am trying to display the fetched api data in my Todo component,
>   above is the code. I am getting the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

The initial state for `items` is an object but should probably be an array. Only arrays have a `map()` function.

```
const initialState = { items: [] };
```

Comment: the api response will be [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  }, .....]

Comment: map can be used with only array, not object but i want to display titles of all objects

Comment: @AbhishekKonnur But your component renders the initial state before your api request completed. Requests are asynchronous. So the initial value in your redux store must be an array too.

Comment: @AbhishekKonnur Change your initial state of `items` to be an array instead of an object.

Comment: Ya I changed to  const initialState = { items: [] };

Comment: @AbhishekKonnur And did it fix your problem?

Comment: Nope still I get this error this.props.items.map is not a function

Comment: @AbhishekKonnur What is the api response? Please console log `res.data`. It is probably not what you expect it to be.

Comment: "Please console log res.data. It is probably not what you expect it to be" - it's amazing how frequently people don't do this....

Comment: axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=10')
    .then(res => dispatch({
      type: 'GET_ITEMS',
      payload: res.data
    }), () => console.log(res.data)
   )
doesn't yield me anything